# OpenGL VAO with GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW

Tags: opengl

I am working with OpenGL and while developing I found this GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW buffers mode that states that buffer data may be changed, and I thought if I call glBufferData(...) while being bound to some VAO does it means that every time I will bing again this VAO all data that was in my memory will be automatically reuploaded to GPU?

Same idea in code:

```py
data = [...] # List of arrays (actual data)
buffers = glGenBuffers(4) # Create buffers

vao = glGenVertexArrays(1) # Create VAO
glBindVertexArray(vao) # Bind VAO

for i, (buf, data) in enumerate(zip(buffers, data)):
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buf)
  glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, data.nbytes, data, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW)
  glEnableVertexAttribArray(i)
  glVertexAttribPointer(i, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, some_straid, ctypes.c_void_p(0))

glBindVertexArray(0) # unbind every thing ...
...

def on_render():
  glClear(...)  # clear screen
  glUseProgram(...)  # enable shader
  
  glBindVertexArray(vao) # will this call upload new data to gpu?
  glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3)  # draw

  glBindVertexArray(0)  # unbind VAO
  glUseProgram(0)  # unbind shader

  glutSwapBuffers()
```

And if not, what is the best way to update those buffers (calling every time glBufferData?)?

Comment: *"does it means that every time I will bing again this VAO all data that was in my memory will be automatically reuploaded to GPU?"* - No, it does not. `glBindVertexArray` just changes a global state. It changes the current VAO object.

Comment: @Rabbid76, so every time I want to update buffer I need to call glBufferData?

Comment: @SlLoWre: Yes. Every time you want to update a buffer, you need to call `glBufferData` (or use one of the memory mapping methods). The usage of `glBufferData` is just a hint for the OpenGL implementation, but doesn't change the functionality in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buffer usage:

> usage is a hint to the GL implementation as to how a buffer object's data store will be accessed. This enables the GL implementation to make more intelligent decisions that may significantly impact buffer object performance. **It does not, however, constrain the actual usage of the data store.** usage can be broken down into two parts: first, the frequency of access (modification and usage), and second, the nature of that access. The frequency of access may be one of these:

For your specific case

> DYNAMIC - The data store contents will be modified repeatedly and used many times.

If you want to update the buffer you have to call `glBufferData` or any of the other methods example: `glBufferSubData`, `glMapBuffer`. This has to be done when the buffer is bound ( Not the VAO, but the buffer )